# Loop through an array of strings and compare to previous values

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I need to loop through an array of strings and know if I've seen a particular string value before.  Normally, I would have written something like this in other languages:

```
String oldValue="";
String newValue;
for (i=0;i<myarray.Length;i++)
{
    newValue=myarray[i];
    if (oldValue==newValue)
        break;
    ...

    oldValue=newValue;

}
```

However, this doesn't work in C# as Strings are immutable.  It looks like I could do this with a Regular Expression if I just replaced the entire string, but that seems like extra overhead.  How have other people handled this before?

Thank you

Comment: Strings are immutable, but you can still assign variables to new values. Can you post a complete code sample demonstrating the problem that you're having? (if you have, refer to Grant's comment above; where have you assigned `newValue`? Obviously this isn't a full program; it wouldn't compile as-is.)

Comment: It doesn't appear as though you've actually attempted this

Comment: Sorry guys I missed setting the newValue.  I've edited it to include.

Comment: Hi Trebor -- I think you misunderstand what immutable strings in .net means. You can still assign a new value to a string variable -- the variable is not read only, or initialize once. The immutability just means that 1. Every time you assign a new value to the string variable, a new string is allocated behind the scenes, and 2. You can't change just one character of a string, like newValue[2] = 'g';

Comment: Chris and JMarsch, you each hit it on the head with what I wasn't understanding.  I had encountered the immutability issue in a previous task and came away thinking they were unchangeable and that you couldn't assign a new value to them.  So I wrote out a demo just to try and prove what I thought to be true, and found out I was completely wrong about how this actually worked.  Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I understood your question, but if what you intend is to detect the first string that is repeated in the array, you need to remember all of them. I suggest using a HashSet, so at least it runs in O(n), like this:

```
HashSet<string> prevSet = new HashSet<string>();

foreach ( string str in myArray )
  if ( !prevSet.Add(str) ) return str;
```

Comment: +1. You can skip `Contains` and just do `if (!prevSet.Add(str)) return str;` See [HashSet.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Danyluis, thank you!  You are correct that I need to really remember all of the previous values and this is a much better solution than what I was thinking of doing.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this to make a list of word frequencies:

```
var frequency =
    myarray
        .GroupBy(x => x)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Value = x.Key,
            Count = x.Count(),
        });
```

You could then just filter this list where `Count > 1`.